# Measure my app performance on Android studio version 3.1.3

Tags: android

I want to measure my app performance with Android Profiler 
it says device not supported and no debuggable processes

[here is Android profiler for lenovo a369I mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XHIM.png)

Comment: Use a different device

Comment: Have you enable debug option true from developer option? Please check it.

Comment: I'm new in android where can I enable debug option

Answer (score 0):

Please go through below step.

Settings-> Developer Options -> USB debugging (Enable this)

If you don't found Developer Option menu then inside setting go to About phone and continue Tap on "Build number". Thus you will get Developer Option menu enabled which is by default not visible that's why.

Comment: who says it's not already enabled? Afaik if it is not enabled then AS does not recognize the device model/make, which it does

Comment: I did usb debugging from beginning learn  android and the app appear on my device

Comment: if you see  the image  I send that is the name of mobile appear at left top of android profiler tab

Comment: After attaching USB cable that time on notification list you will get Two notification from those both when you tap one of them then one will open developer option another will open one dialog. So when you get dialog then which option is selected? If you selected option is "Use device as MIDI" then select another any option from available options.